# Stop a thread by a tkinter trigger?

Tags: multithreading, windows-7, tkinter, python-3.3

I'm making a program that displays a messagebox and plays a .wav file through a thread at the same time. The problem is, the sound file is big, and I would like it to stop playing after I press 'OK'. Any help would be appreciated. I'm using Python 3.3 on Windows 7. Here's my code for the box and audio:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=winsound.PlaySound, args=("C:/Interactive Program/LIP Source Files/skyisup.wav", 2))
t1.start()
lipgui.msgbox("The sky is up!")
```

Comment: & what actually is happening when you press 'OK'?

Comment: Nothing the program goes back to the menu as it was told to do in the loop, and the audio just keeps playing!

Comment: & how are you killing the audio...kindly provide more relevant code

Comment: I tried stopping the thread by running t1.join(), but it didn't work. I also tried to run winsound.PlaySound(None, 2) to try to stop the sound.

Comment: Doesn't `join` method waits for the thread to finish? Or thats what i read,I haven't actually used it.

Comment: Well, I'm new to programming, but that's what I read. I've also tried t1.close() or t1.exit() not sure which is actually an actual method.

Comment: Actually I'm new too :P ...try searching for methods for killing threads or killing your audio...i think you are not killing the audio,just the thread maybe

Comment: Ok, I'll look some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. What I needed to do was pass winsound.SND_ASYNC to winsound.PlaySound() instead of '2'. Then stop the audio by passing winsound.PlaySound(None, 0)!